# Dynamically initialize object on Runtime depending on requirement

Tags: c#

Given that I have an object with structure as below :-

```
RootObject
   Personal
      Forename
      Surname
      Middlename
   Telephone
      LandLine
      Mobile
```

And when I supplied

```
<Ruleset>
   <Field>Personal.Forename</Field>
   <FieldValue>World</Field>
</Ruleset>
<Ruleset>
   <Field>Personal.Surname</Field>
   <FieldValue>Hello</Field>
</Ruleset>
```

When I supplier Ruleset

I wanted the 'Personal' object in RootObject to be initialized depending on the requirement while Telephone is not initialize (and vice-versa).

Please advice how am I able to achieve this without having it to code initialization / constructor code throughout the whole RootObject child (and child's child) as I'm looking for a dynamic solution that can be use without having to rework on the initialization piece of code. Thanks

Comment: Vote down person please kindly provide explanation.

This is not a "homework" stuff as I have tried a couple of ways including casting it to object and perform.GetType() then initialize it. 

Just that whenever a new class in the Root object exist, I have to update the whole GetType() switch.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understood you correctly, but if you want you can use reflection.

If you `RuleSet` looks something like this:

```
public class RulleSet
    {
         public string ObjectName { get; set; }
         public string PropertyName { get; set; }
         public object value { get; set; }
    }
```

You can create method at you class:

```
public void Initialize(RulleSet initRule)
    {
        var initializableObject = this.GetType().GetProperty(initRule.ObjectName).GetValue(this,null);
        //If object not initialized, we need to create it
        if (initializableObject == null)
        {
            initializableObject =
                Activator.CreateInstance(this.GetType().GetProperty(initRule.ObjectName).PropertyType);
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty(initRule.ObjectName);
            propertyInfo.SetValue(this, Convert.ChangeType(initializableObject, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
        }
        //If we have object, we created it or it already axist doesn't matter we set property
        if (initializableObject != null)
        {
            var initializableProperty =
                initializableObject.GetType().GetProperty(initRule.PropertyName).GetValue(initializableObject, null);
            initializableProperty = Activator.CreateInstance(initializableObject.GetType().GetProperty(initRule.PropertyName).PropertyType);
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = initializableObject.GetType().GetProperty(initRule.PropertyName);
            propertyInfo.SetValue(initializableObject, Convert.ChangeType(initializableProperty, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
        }
    }
```

Didn't test :) so there might be some bugs, if you want you can make it static, just add additional parameter in method which will represent you initialization object, and replace `this` with this parameter.
PS. ofc due to using reflection it might be slower neither coded initialization.